# Edit text color of individual Rows in ListView Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

So I have this code

```
public ListView listView = new ListView();
    List<string> rolesList = new List<string>();
rolesList.Add("Master Admin");
            rolesList.Add("Admin");
listView.ItemsSource = rolesList;
            Content = listView;
```

So this creates a list view with two items in it. I'd like to make the first item have green text, and the second have red text color, how would I do this programmatically? In other words I need to be able to change text color at a given index. Thanks for any help, Ben.

Comment: Why don't use xaml?

Comment: @JoakimM i need to be able to change it programmatically based on information I'm receiving from my backend.

Comment: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/27896/listview-alternating-row-background-colors

Comment: I think if you have too many colors for the listview its easier to create a Color property in your model and bind it to that. I know its not a clean approach since we are having a xaml element in the model but it works. If not this you can always use valueconverters to set the background color based on the model property.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to achieve that is by using a `DataTemplateSelector`. This class allows, in runtime, to choose between two DataTemplates, according to some property.

First, you need to create your DataTemplateSelector

```
public class DummyDataTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
  public DataTemplate ValidTemplate { get; set; }
  public DataTemplate InvalidTemplate { get; set; }

  protected override DataTemplate OnSelectTemplate (object item, BindableObject container)
  {
    return ((YourClass)item).YourProperty == Admin ? TemplateColor1 : TemplateColor2;
  }
}
```

In `XAML`:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Selector;assembly=Selector" x:Class="Selector.HomePage">
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="template1">
                <ViewCell>
                   ...
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="template2">
                <ViewCell>
                   ...
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
            <local:DummyTemplateSelector x:Key="dummyDataTemplateSelector"
                ValidTemplate="{StaticResource template1}"
                InvalidTemplate="{StaticResource template2}" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>
  ...
</ContentPage>
```

To finish, add that template selector to your Listview:

```
<ListView x:Name="listView" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource dummyTemplateSelector}" />
```